# Code works in Firefox Scratchpad but not in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar to load a Google Calendar. I want to convert all the `a` tags of a certain class in the calendar to `span`s. My code works great if I execute it in Scratchpad, after the page has loaded, but if I put it right after the calendar code in my JavaScript file, it doesn't do anything (all of the `a`s are still `a`s.) Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventSources: [
        'MY CALENDAR URL',
        {
            url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
            className: 'holiday'
        }
      ],
      header: {
        left:   'title',
        center: '',
        right:  'prev,next'
      }
  });
  var aclass = $('a.holiday').attr('class');
  var astyle = $('a.holiday').attr('style');
  var atext = $('a.holiday').html();
  $('a.holiday').replaceWith('<span style="'+ astyle +'" class="'+ aclass +'">'+ atext +'</span>');
});
```

Only two errors show in the JS Error Console:

> [17:34:08.182] Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated. 
>   Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead.
>
> [17:34:08.663] SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate source map URL
>   pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead

Neither of them seem related to my problem. One is located in jQuery and the other in requestNotifier.js.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: You may need to run that on page load, not DOM load.

Comment: @Juhana: no errors are related to my problem.

Comment: @Joe: Tried that but it still didn't work. (using `$(window).load()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FullCalendar provides some nice hooks that you can use to style the events as you would like.

One way to get the job done, is simply to move your current code into `eventAfterAllRender`, like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  [...]
  eventAfterAllRender: function() {
    var aclass = $('a.holiday').attr('class');
    var astyle = $('a.holiday').attr('style');
    var atext = $('a.holiday').html();
    $('a.holiday').replaceWith('<span style="'+ astyle +'" class="'+ aclass +'">'+ atext +'</span>');
  }
  [...]
});
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, which made it easy to rerun the code after every month change.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got this figured out: the calendar has to be compeltely loaded, so separating the code with different events works well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventSources: [
        'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/r9iglfiamf6s7vr61lspgaa35g%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        {
            url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
            className: 'holiday'
        }
      ],
      header: {
        left:   'title',
        center: '',
        right:  'prev,next'
      }
  });
});
$(window).load(function() {
  var aclass = $('a.holiday').attr('class');
  var astyle = $('a.holiday').attr('style');
  var atext = $('a.holiday').html();
  $('a.holiday').replaceWith('<span style="'+ astyle +'" class="'+ aclass +'">'+ atext +'</span>');
});
```